# Dividing a pandas dataframe column of dtype float64 by a floating number is returning only integer

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, floating-point, division

I am using python 3.6.5 and I am getting this problem:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a' : [1,2,3] , 'b' : [4,5,7]} , dtype = np.float64)
```

and if I do any kind of division, for instance

```
df['a']/2.0 = 0   0
              1   1
              2   2
              Name: a, dtype: float64
```

And actually even if I try to build a dataframe using an array containing decimals, pd.DataFrame is turning everything into integer, eventhough it says that the dtype is float64. Thanx for ur help

Comment: I can't reproduce, works for me.  Python 3.6.5, pandas 0.23.0

Comment: Did you by any chance ever set `np.float64 = int`? Because that would give you the initial behavior, but even so, dividing by a float should change the column.

Comment: No at all. I can't understant this beavior of pandas dataframe and pandas series. Even when Iam doing this for instance 
     value = df['a'].values/3 
    value
    outpt : array([0.33333333, 0.66666667, 1.        ])

    and then I tr to do something like that
    pd.Series(data = value, dtype = np.float64)
The resulting series is only full of 0's

Comment: Really weird behavior. If you open a brand new terminal python3 and type exactly that code, does it still happen?

Comment: Really weired, yes It works in python terminal... So I don't know what's the problem with jupyter

Comment: It works in a terminal. where could the problem come from as I am working with jupyter notebook. I dont know because I tried everything....